# Why my private app not installed in dedicated device profile?

Tags: android, android-management-api, android-enterprise-features

I have been working with **Android management API** for the last few months and Uploaded two private apps in the **EMM console**.It was working perfectly while I distributed to dedicated device.But now It is not installed while I distribute.I can't understand what is actually the problem is?.For more information I have attached a screenshot below where shows me that one app available but 0 installed.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem a few days ago.I have solved this problem by doing allow regions for the app from private google play console.For doing this you need to do following things

1. Click on your private app
2. At right corner click **make advanced edits**
3. In private play console allow **regions/country** for this app